# How to watch a log file remotely for a period of time before disconnecting

Tags: unix, ssh, watch

I left out a very important part of this situation.  The 'watch' command is part of a script that is scanning a series of hosts.  The ssh sessions are created on the fly within the script. And there are several logs on each host that I'd like to watch.  I've tried setting "ConnectTimeout=10" for instance to at least get it to move onto the next host but that doesn't affect how long it maintains the connection.  Killing the ssh process seems to kill the script somehow.

Is there any way to use `watch` in an `ssh` session so that it only watches the target file for a set period of time before disconnecting?  I know that you can use `top` in a batch manner and I'd like to be able to do the same thing with `watch`.

I don't see anything in the man pages and I haven't found anything in Internet searches where someone's been able to do this.  Nor can I find an alternative to watch that can visually show changes to a file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply kill the `watch` process after some time if that is all you need. If you run this as the command you pass to `ssh` so your `ssh` session will terminate when `watch` exits.

```
(sleep 3; kill `ps -C watch -o pid=`) & watch ls
```